# COMPOSER　を認証付きのProxyServer越しにインストールするには？

Tags: composer

標題のとおりですが、社内でCOMPOSERをインストールしようとしている関係で
ID・Passwordの認証を必要とするProxyServerを介す必要があります。

この時、どういった入力を下記画面で行えばよろしいのでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

追記：
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

追記：
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

追記：
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ところでcomposer自体はpharなのでインストーラーを使わずとも使うだけであれば可能です。まあ、インストーラーでこのようなエラーが出てるのであればそちらでやっても同じエラーにはなるでしょうが。

Comment: hinaloeさんの仰るとおりコマンドラインからの実装で無事達成されました、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ユーザー名やプロキシサーバーの情報が以下の場合、

```
ユーザー名：USER
パスワード：PASS
プロキシサーバ：PROXY_SERVER
ポート番号：PROXY_PORT
```

以下のフォーマットで入力してみてください(`<>`は要らないです、念のため)。

```
http://<USER>:<PASS>@<PROXY_SERVER>:<PROXY_PORT>
```

Comment: いつもご支援ありがとうございます、次はこのエラーが現れました、一体何が悪いのでしょう?本文に貼り付けました

Comment: COMPOSERのインストールが必要になった背景は、CAKE PHP3系のセットアップを検討しているためです。
CAKE PHPの導入にあたってはCOMPOSERを使わない手はない、という記事が散見されもう泣きそう．．．

Comment: エラーが何か表示された場合、まずは自分で「調べてみる」習慣をつけましょう。追記の内容についてはSSLの証明書絡みのエラーらしく、プロキシは関係なく表示されるそうです ([参考](https://blog.shimabox.net/2016/10/25/install-composer/))。Composerの「マニュアルインストール」という方法もあるようなので確認してみてください ([公式の手順](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#manual-installation))

Comment: http://blue-goheimochi.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/09/15/Laravel4%E3%81%A7composer_install%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89openssl%E3%81%8C%E5%BF%85%E8%A6%81%E3%81%A0%E3%82%88%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E3%81%9F%E4%BB%B6で、
php.iniでphp_openssl.dllを有効にする、という具体的な解決策の記載がありましたので、
飛びついてコメントアウトされていたextension=php_openssl.dllをコメント解除しました。
この上で、COMPSERのインストーラ（.exe）を再実行すると．．．
自身のphp.iniにextension=php_openssl.dllの記述が2箇所以上あったとみえ
次に、別エラーメッセージが現われるようになってしまいました。（本文に追加）

2回読み込んでいる、というエラー内容と思いますが、コメントアウトを元に戻せば
本文2番目に貼り付けたエラーメッセージがでますし．．．堂々めぐりです。

Comment: 私が回答したのはあくまで「プロキシ設定」に対してのみです。証明書エラーに関わるComposerのインストールについては先のコメントでも言及した通り [手動インストール](http://laravel.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/11/18/004325) を試してもらうか、改めて別質問として投稿してください。

Comment: 貴重なお時間を頂き、誠にありがとうございます。
早速ですが、仰られているように手動インストール、というを是非に試行してみたいのですが
cubickさんが紹介されたページで「Composerのサイトからhttp://getcomposer.org/composer.pharをダウンロードして」
と記載されている部分で早速躓いております。
自身のIEの設定が故のことなのか、URLの部分をクリックしたら　ダウンロードどころか
文字化けしたページが表れる　だけの状態に陥ります。

要因を特定できていない関係で、問合せ内容が変化してしまって申し訳ないです。（問合せタイトルに柔軟性を持たせるべきかな）

Comment: `.phar`ファイルは単純なテキストファイルではなく、PHPで扱うアーカイブ形式の一つです ([参考](http://php.net/manual/ja/book.phar.php)) 。そのまま読めるスクリプトの部分と、アーカイブなので読めない(文字化けしたように見える)部分とが一つのファイルにまとめられています。

Comment: ダウンロードの操作方法がわからないのですが、URL（http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar）にアクセスして
画面に表示された内容をコピペ、そしてその内容を
http://getcomposer.org/composer.pharという名前のファイルで保存、
ということではないのですよね？？何から何まで無知ですみません。恥ずかしい限りです。

Comment: 会社の端末でcomposer.pharをサイトからダウンロードできない問題で躓いておりましたが
①自宅のChromeで取得して、会社に持参（php.exeの環境に配置）
②環境変数pathにphp.exeの所在パスを追加
③composer.batをcubickさんご紹介の記事に従って作成＆②の環境に配置
④composer.batをコマンドプロンプトで実行
これでなんとかcomposerのセットアップが無事行われたようです。

諦めないで良かった．．．ご支援をありがとございました。
これからCAKEPHPのインストール？！に挑戦です